# Identifying dupes in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, count, duplicates, distinct

I have a table `TEMP` with columns `Ticker`, `Date` and `Price`:

```
Ticker    Date        price
----------------------------
ABC       01/01/13    100.00 
ABC       01/02/13    101.50 
ABC       01/03/13     99.80 
ABC       01/04/13     95.50 
ABC       01/05/13     78.00 
XYZ       01/01/13     11.50 
XYZ       01/02/13     12.10 
XYZ       01/02/13     12.10 
XYZ       01/03/13     17.15 
XYZ       01/04/13     14.10 
XYZ       01/05/13     15.55
```

Note that I have a duplicate for XYZ on 01/02/13

I'm trying to identify dupes using the `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` statements in SQL, but I am having problems.

Here's my code and the error msg:

```
SELECT 
    Date,
    Price,
    COUNT([Ticker]) 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         Ticker, Date 
     FROM 
         [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[temp]
     WHERE 
         COUNT[Ticker] > 1) AS dt
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Ticker'.

What's the best way to identify duplicate entries for each ticker/date?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT Ticker, Date, Price, COUNT(*)
FROM [Coinmarketcap].[dbo].[temp] t
GROUP BY Ticker, Date, Price
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

At least, this identifies the duplicate as you have defined it in your question.